# Trying to parse JSON in Java (using Gson), getting MalformedJsonException

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson

I am trying to get weather forecast data from the WeatherUnderground API.

So far I am using the following code:

```
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.connect();

JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

JsonElement forecastJson = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent())).getAsJsonObject()
        .getAsJsonObject().get("forecast")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("simpleforecast")
        .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("forecastday").get(1);

System.out.println("forecastJson = " + forecastJson.toString());

String date = String.valueOf(jp.parse(forecastJson
        .getAsJsonObject().get("date")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("epoch").getAsString()));

String high = String.valueOf(jp.parse(forecastJson
        .getAsJsonObject().get("high")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("celsius").getAsString()));

String low = String.valueOf(jp.parse(forecastJson
        .getAsJsonObject().get("low")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("celsius").getAsString()));

String conditions;
try {
    conditions = String.valueOf(jp.parse(forecastJson
            .getAsJsonObject().get("conditions").getAsString()));
} catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The JsonElement forecastJson" I receive looks like this:

```
{
  "date": {
    "epoch": "1467046800",
    "pretty": "7:00 PM CEST on June 27, 2016",
    "day": 27,
    "month": 6,
    "year": 2016,
    "yday": 178,
    "hour": 19,
    "min": "00",
    "sec": 0,
    "isdst": "1",
    "monthname": "June",
    "monthname_short": "Jun",
    "weekday_short": "Mon",
    "weekday": "Monday",
    "ampm": "PM",
    "tz_short": "CEST",
    "tz_long": "Europe/Berlin"
  },
  "period": 2,
  "high": {
    "fahrenheit": "77",
    "celsius": "25"
  },
  "low": {
    "fahrenheit": "58",
    "celsius": "14"
  },
  "conditions": "Partly Cloudy",
  "icon": "partlycloudy",
  "icon_url": "http://icons.wxug.com/i/c/k/partlycloudy.gif",
  "skyicon": "",
  "pop": 0,
  "qpf_allday": {
    "in": 0,
    "mm": 0
  },
  "qpf_day": {
    "in": 0,
    "mm": 0
  },
  "qpf_night": {
    "in": 0,
    "mm": 0
  },
  "snow_allday": {
    "in": 0,
    "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_day": {
    "in": 0,
    "cm": 0
  },
  "snow_night": {
    "in": 0,
    "cm": 0
  },
  "maxwind": {
    "mph": 15,
    "kph": 24,
    "dir": "W",
    "degrees": 260
  },
  "avewind": {
    "mph": 11,
    "kph": 18,
    "dir": "W",
    "degrees": 260
  },
  "avehumidity": 48,
  "maxhumidity": 0,
  "minhumidity": 0
}
```

I am able to get the "date", "high" and "low" Strings, but I'm unable to get the "conditions" and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

I am getting the following exception:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON
```

As far as I understand the JSON is not malformed. How am I supposed to get the "conditions" value?

I've tried other JSON parsers / libraries as well, but nothing worked out. I'd like to continue working with the Gson-Library, and I guess I'm quite close, but stuck.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: BTW, the exception says "Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON", but like I wrote, I don't see the JSON being malformed, and besides that I don't create a JsonReader anywhere, so I don't know at which point I could apply "setLenient(true).

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why do you parse the whole JSON, and then try to re-parse all its elements? Parse the JSON, then just access its elements. No need to re-parse them.

Comment: Why don't you create a class for the json data and use `TheClass foo = gson.fromJson(theJson, TheClass.class)` and then use `foo`?

Comment: @ JB Nizet: I'm quite the beginner to Java and Json, so yeah, I actually thought I need to parse the JSON every time to get something from it. Your question made me aware that I was doing that wrong. Thanks for the help, I get the "conditions" now as well!

Comment: @ RC.: OK I'm gonna try that out, looks like a good way. Like I already wrote on my other comment, I'm quite the beginner, so that's the answer to "Why don't you ..." :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you break down the line that's throwing the exception you can see that you are actually trying to parse as JSON a string that is in fact *not* JSON.

```
try {
    JsonObject jo = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement je = jo.get("conditions");
    String s1 = je.getAsString();

    // at this point s1 contains the value "Partly Cloudy" which you 
    // are trying to parse as JSON.
    JsonElement je2  = jp.parse(s1);


    conditions = String.valueOf(je2);
} catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As "JB Nizet" pointed out in the comment under my question, I was trying to parse the JSON every time again when I wanted to get another piece of its contents. That was my (beginner) mistake.

Now I parse only once and then get the contents directly, without any problem:

```
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();

JsonElement forecastJson = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent())).getAsJsonObject()
        .getAsJsonObject().get("forecast")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("simpleforecast")
        .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonArray("forecastday").get(1);

String date = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject().get("date")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("epoch").getAsString();

String high = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject().get("high")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("celsius").getAsString();

String low = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject().get("low")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("celsius").getAsString();

String conditions = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject()
        .get("conditions").getAsString();
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, as they say in the comments there's really no need to parse every piece again.

`String date = String.valueOf(jp.parse(forecastJson
        .getAsJsonObject().get("date")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("epoch").getAsString()));`

Is the same as: 

`String date = forecastJson.getAsJsonObject().get("date")
        .getAsJsonObject().get("epoch").getAsString();`

The problem that you're experiencing is actually something that I suspect is a bug in the Gson library. When it tries to parse a string with spaces in it, it will tokenize that string and expect that after the first word (**Partly** in this case) the document should end and that the json is malformed since it hasn't reached the end of the document.

So to solve this, either do as the comments say, which is the reasonable thing in your case. Or if you wan't you could always change *Partly cloudy* to for example *Partly_cloudy* and it will work :)

Comment: @JJF that's okay I've tested it locally and looked at the GSON source code, I think my answer is pretty correct.
In your answer your saying that trying to parse a string is incorrect but thats whats happening before several times before the exception. You can also try putting the string "Partly cloudy" into jsonlint.com and see what happens.

Comment: I did paste his data into JSON lint and it verified ok.  Also there is no other place in his code where he is trying to parse invalid json.  Every prior call to .parse() is called on valid JSON to get the value of a nested element.   He just has a call to .parse() that he doesn't need because in this last case there is no further nested object.  A bug in GSON that obvious and fatal seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @JJF Yes, every prior call is to valid json, but they're still strings, the only difference is that the prior strings do not have spaces in them. *date.epoch* is a string, *high.celcius* and *low.celcius* are also strings, both in the json and explicitly since *getAsString()* is called.